# "Could not find rake in any of the sources" when calling ruby script from a GEM

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a GEM that I build from a project I have, let's call it **MyGEM**. In the bin directory of MyGEM, I have a **MyShellScript.sh** that calls rvm to switch to JRuby and runs a script using JRuby that also exists in MYGEM but in another directory, this script is called  **MyRubyScript.rb**

I added MyGEM to another ruby project that I am using called **MyProject**. Now in MyProject, after installing MyGEM, I called `bundle exec MyShellScript.sh`. The commands ran fine, but when MyShellScript.sh calls MyRubyScript.sh, I get the following error:

> Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources

I tried to call `bundle install rake`, `bundle update` and `gem install rake` and I still get the same error. Also it seems that I get this error with any ruby command, even if it is not related to rake. So, for example, I get it when I call `gem list` in MyShellScript.sh and also I get it when I clear MyRubyScript.rb and put only `puts "Hello"` in it and then call `bundle exec MyShellScript.sh` again from MyProject.

Also, when I go to the MyGEM location from MyProject using `cd $(bundle show MyGEM)/bin` and then call the script using `./MyShellScript.sh`, it works fine and I do not get the rake error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue in OS X and the following fixed it for me

```
brew install llvm
ruby-install rbx 2.3.0 -i ~/.rubies/rbx -- --llvm-config /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/llvm-config
```

Comment: I am on linux.. How could this resolve it for me? I do not understand what does it do?